# java quartz cron schedule error

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

sorry for the english (i'm not a native speaker), i wanted to build a job for test.This job might just display a simple message "test job".I have build the classes but i have some errors that i don't really understand.

```
import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class TestCrons {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
        job.setName("dummyJobName");
        job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);
        job.setGroup(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);


        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
        trigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
        trigger.setGroup(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP);

        try {
         trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 11 18 * ?");

         //schedule it
         Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
         scheduler.start();
         scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }
       catch(Exception e)
       {

         System.out.println("erro :-p ");
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
 }

}
```

This is my HelloJob class

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

public class HelloJob implements Job{

@Override
   public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("test job");

  }

}
```

When i run my TestCrons class i have this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.quartz.CronTrigger.computeFirstFireTime(CronTrigger.java:1086)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:569)
at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:221)
at sn.orange.test.TestCrons.main(TestCrons.java:30)
```

Can anyone help me please.

Another question,why do i have applets which ask me authorizations when running TestCrons class ?

Comment: check the code at line `TestCrons.java:#30`. You might be getting `null` value there.

Comment: what is the version of quartz you are using?

Comment: make sure your cron expression is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NullPointerException when using the no-arg constructor for CronTrigger if you don't set the start time yourself.

You'll need to make a call to setStartTime() or use a different constructor.

Comment: I have change the constructor.But i have another question.Why do i have applets asking for authorizations when i run TestCrons class?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: When i run the class, i have an applet that displays me this message : the applet is attempting to access the "exists" state of file C:\Users\tmp_samb\workspace\ProjetQuartz\quartz.properties

Comment: The authorizations came from that you are using an applet, and applets have to run in a limited mode in order to maintain your computer safe, because they can be launched from any web page.

Comment: The problem is that i don't want these applets to appear because i will deploy the application soon.Is there any way to give auhtorizations to quartz without displaying applets?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Plabo Gallego,i have changed constructor.This is the code

```
import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class TestCrons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            JobDetail job = new JobDetail(Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP,"dummyJobName",HelloJob.class);

       CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("TriggerGroup","dummyTriggerName","0 36 12 18 * ?");


             //schedule it
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {

              System.out.println("erro :-p ");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }

    }
```